# Use DataProtection to unprotect, throws "The payload was invalid"

Tags: c#, .net

I encrypted a string by .Net Framework 4.8:

```
var dataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\SharedKeys\"), builder =>
{
  builder.SetApplicationName("myApp");
});

var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookies", "v2");
var text = dataProtector.Protect("abc");
```

The result is: "CfDJ8GHt0XxGzaFBlFEwKShBTYZTKFl3jI6DiCAmTaackE0ymGCf_WeBXN2CL4RHN1i9o5kK5fms-9ZmFHV8-e-3bRd0yR5YOxBdcQoxajS9vCe5lrMNZ0gze0PZ-yfV8kqSMQ";

Then I use .Net SDK 6.0 to decrypt it:

```
var protectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(
            new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\SharedKeys\"), cfg => cfg.SetApplicationName("myApp"));
var dataProtector = protectionProvider.CreateProtector(
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware", "Cookie", "v2");
var result = dataProtector.Unprotect(
    "CfDJ8GHt0XxGzaFBlFEwKShBTYZTKFl3jI6DiCAmTaackE0ymGCf_WeBXN2CL4RHN1i9o5kK5fms-9ZmFHV8-e-3bRd0yR5YOxBdcQoxajS9vCe5lrMNZ0gze0PZ-yfV8kqSMQ");
```

but it throws "The payload was invalid":

```
if (!CryptoUtil.TimeConstantBuffersAreEqual(correctHash, 0, correctHash.Length, protectedPayload.Array!, macOffset, eofOffset - macOffset))
{
   throw Error.CryptCommon_PayloadInvalid(); // integrity check failure
}
```

It seems like the mac is not correct.
anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Have you tried encrypting "abc" and then immediately decrypting it into a new variable using the same `dataProtector` instance and comparing the result? This will highlight if there's an issue with instance creation.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo.
The sub-purpose, in the first program is "cookies",
and the second one, it's "cookie".
ChatGPT helped.